# Modal isn't opening as expected

Tags: reactjs

```
class Posts extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            modalIsOpen:false
        };
        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
        this.afterOpenModal = this.afterOpenModal.bind(this);
        this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
    }
    openModal() {
        console.log("got here?")
        this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
    }
    afterOpenModal() {
        // references are now sync'd and can be accessed.
        this.subtitle.style.color = '#f00';
    }
    closeModal() {
        this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
    }
    render() {
        const keys = generateKey(new Date().getTime())
        var dictionary = this.props.posts
        const postItemsArr = Object.keys(dictionary).map(post=>dictionary[post])
        const number = 0
        const postItems = postItemsArr.map(
            post=>(
                <Jumbotron  key={generateKey(post.positiontitle) + generateKey(post.businessId)} >
                    <div className="position">{post.positiontitle}</div><br></br>
                    <BusinessName businessnameType={post.businessname} /><br></br>
                    <JobDescription jobDescription={post.description_sanitized} /><br></br>
                    <p>
                        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                            onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
                            onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
                            style={customStyles}
                            contentLabel="Example"
                        >
                            <h2 ref={subtitle => this.subtitle = subtitle}>Hello</h2>
                            <button onClick={this.closeModal}>close</button>
                            <div>I am a modal</div>
                            <form>
                                <input />
                                <button>tab navigation</button>
                                <button>stays</button>
                                <button>inside</button>
                                <button>the modal</button>
                            </form>
                        </Modal>
                        <button onClick={this.openModal}>Open Modal</button>
                    </p>
                </Jumbotron> 
            )
        )
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> Jobs Listings </h1>
                {postItems }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Inside my Jumbotron, my modal doesn't seem to be opening, why?

It looks like it gets to the state  openModal()

but doesn't actually open the modal when the user clicks on

```
<button onClick={this.openModal}>Open Modal</button>
```

Also; should I create a separate component called Modal; what would be best practices?

Overall I'm trying to trigger the modal object for a respective list item in the list.

Comment: which `<Modal>` are you using here ?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new presentational component called modal, then use that when you need it, rather than do what you're trying to do now, which is pass an open/close state. The Modal can be a simple presentational component that just accepts props. By doing it this way, you create reusability.

```
function Modal(props) {
  return (
    <div className={props.css.awesomeLayout}>
      {props.aProp}
    </div>
  )
}
```